# How do you add Margin to an Element with the flex-end property?

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I am trying to position a View in the top right corner of the screen in my react native app and have done so using: `alignSelf: 'flex-end'` with `position: absolute`. This works, however I now want to add a margin around the box with `margin: 15` but this doesn't work. The View has margin on the top but not on the right, presumably because my usage of `flex-end` places the View as far left as possible. How do I override this and add margin all around the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use `alignSelf: 'flex-end'`, since you have already `position: 'absolute'`, use `top: 15` and `right: 15` to have it at top right with 15 pixels distance:

```jsx
<View style={{
  flex: 0,
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 15,
  right: 15
}}>...</View>
```